# Postgres pg_background_launch permission denied

Tags: postgresql

I was trying to implement autonomous transaction in Postgres by using pg_background extension. Although it is installed, I can't call the function pg_background_launch.

Command `CREATE EXTENSION pg_background` returns error **ERROR:  extension "pg_background" already exists**, so I know it already exists.

But when I run query `SELECT pg_background_launch('SELECT 1');` it returns error **ERROR:  permission denied for function pg_background_launch**

Any idea, what did I miss? Is it needed to grant some privileges? In the documentation here https://github.com/vibhorkum/pg_background, there is nothing more done after creating the extension.

Answer (score 0):

You need the user who created the extension to grant out access to the functions to other users:

```
GRANT ALL ON FUNCTION public.pg_background_launch(sql text, queue_size integer) to some_user;
GRANT ALL ON FUNCTION public.pg_background_result(pid integer) to some_user;
GRANT ALL ON FUNCTION public.pg_background_detach(pid integer) to some_user;
```